# Sistema nao abre no Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Tenho um sistema local (desenvolvimento). Criei um virtual host no windows (exemplo.dev). Quando tento acessa-lo no Chrome, ele adiconal 'https://' e nao me deixa acessar. No mozilla funcional perfeitamente. Como voltar a usar o Chrome (versão atual: 63.0.3239.108 (Versão oficial) 64 bits) ?

Comment: Tirando o HTTPS da frente (?)

Comment: As vezes é por questão de segurança. Coloca um protocolo HTTPS no seu sistema. Aqui tem um plano free que pode te ajudar. https://www.cloudflare.com/br/plans/#moredetail ou tenta tira o S do final e ver se passa...